# Book a tour to Machu Picchu from Cusco on arrival

Tags: peru, backpacking, south-america, machu-picchu, cusco

I've visited Machu Picchu back in 2019, it was a tour booked from Loki Hostel when I arrived there, like 1-2 days before the starting date. It was a 3 day/2 nights, transport, food and accommodation included and I paid aprox 150 USD.

I would like to go again in January 2024, so I've wrote to Loki Hostel about it, they say they don't organise tours anymore and redirected me to Aita Tours. Checked their website and a [tour](https://www.aitaperu.com/inca-jungle-tour-to-machupicchu-3d2n) that seems similar to mine costs $395.

Has the price become that high since then? It seems a huge difference.

My question is if there is anyone who did this trip recently and booked a tour directly from Cusco, what was the cost and how can I get to the organisers?